# Wedge product is zero

Tags: differential-forms

Suppose $C$ is a scalar, $\mathcal{Y}$ is one-form and there is the equation

$$ dC\wedge \mathcal{Y}=0 \quad (1)$$

What is the most general solution of this equation?

Using the geometrical interpretation of the wedge product I would say that there is a solution
$$ \mathcal{Y}=f(C)dC,\quad (2)$$ 
but is this the most general one? Probably the answer is no, but I would like to know other opinions.

In the tensorial form the equation (1) is
$$\partial_s C  Y_t - Y_s \partial_t C=0,\quad (3)$$
here $\mathcal{Y}=Y_adx^a$. Obviously (2) is a solution, but again it is not clear that (2) is the most general one.

Comment: Equation (3) implies that $(\partial_1 C, \cdots, \partial_n C)$ are parallel to $(Y_1, \cdots, Y_n)$. So it seems that (2) is quite general (at least when both vectors are nonzero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the theorem (Theorem 3 in [Wedge Product](http://www.tulane.edu/~ftbirtel/wedge%20product.pdf)) saying that $v_1\wedge v_2\wedge \cdots \wedge v_k=0$ if and only if $$v_j=\sum_{i=1,i\ne j} a_i v_i$$
for some $j$, $j\le 1\le k$. Applying it to (1) we get the most general solution in the form
$$\mathcal{Y}=f dC,$$
with some arbitrary function $f$. The solution (2) is correct ONLY if we require additionally $d\mathcal{Y}=0$, which gives $f=f(C)$.

Answer (score 1):

For some 1-forms $X$ and $Y$ written as
\begin{eqnarray}
X &= \varepsilon_1 dx^1 + \varepsilon_2 dx^2 + \cdots + \varepsilon_n dx^n \\
Y &= \pi_1 dx^1 + \pi_2 dx^2 + \cdots + \pi_n dx^n
\end{eqnarray}

Then the condition
\begin{eqnarray}
X \wedge Y &= 0 \\
\implies \sum_{1\le i<j \le n}(\varepsilon_i\pi_j-\pi_i\varepsilon_j)dx^i\wedge dx^j &=0
\end{eqnarray}

And the result you're looking for follows.